# Where do I find slow and dry moving zombies for the quest "They Never Stop Coming"?

Tags: the-secret-world

On tier 3 of the quest 'They Never Stop Coming' from Norma Creed, you need to kill four specific kinds of zombie.

The four kinds you're asked for are:

- Zombie cultists
- Fast and dry moving zombies
- Slow and dry moving zombies
- Wet zombies

I have found that wet zombies appear to just be Mariner zombies out on the street in front of her house, and that the cultists can be found in the field behind Norma's house (Reawakened Cultists). The fast zombies are pretty much everywhere (Returned Townies) but where do I find slow and dry moving zombies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a location a lot closer where you can find the slow and dry moving zombies. And that is if you go from Norma's house, to the street and turn right following the street till you reach a fence. Reaching the beach and close to pyramid point.
Past the fence are cultists, and walking around in that area are called (reawakened, or something else will check later on) warrior. Also there are Slow and Dry zombies at the Graveyard, behind the church (Dearly Departed.) These count as Dry and slow zombies.

In that location you can get both the cultists and slow and dry.

I'll post a screenshot later on.

Comment: I forgot to take a screenshot, ill do it tonight :p

Answer (score 3):

They can be found in the graveyard at the church.

Answer (score 1):

I got the Slow and Dry Zombies in the graveyard behind the church.  (The 'Dearly Departed')

Answer (score 1):

- First is Zombie Cultists (Zombie Cultists)
- Then its regular crazed rippers and returned townie (Fast Dry Moving Zombies)
- Then dearly departed (Slow Moving Dy Zombies)
- Last is drowned Mariner (Wet Zombies)

Answer (score -1):

The wet and slow zombies are reanimated warriors spawning on the beach.